# Cakephp ClassRegistry::init in bootstrap

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, bootstrapping

can I use a model in bootstrap.php to get an array with find() from database ?

like this :

```
$Setting = ClassRegistry::init('Setting');
$Settings = $Setting->find('all');
```

thanks

Comment: well then you shoudnt ask if thats possible but display the errors you got (which you must have gotten because you are asking). try to be as specific as possible.

Comment: @mark you say its not possible ?

Comment: i have this error : Fatal error: Class 'ClassRegistry' not found

Comment: now that it more helpful to us, of course :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to manually load the used classes then, if you really must use core internal stuff that early.

try

```
App::uses('ClassRegistry', 'Utility');
```

before you actually use ClassRegistry.

Comment: now is it correct job ? ( i'm use it for load site settings from database and cache them )

Answer (score 2):

Write in bootstrap.php

```
App::uses('ClassRegistry', 'Utility');
$Setting = ClassRegistry::init('ModelName');
```